# How to optimize multiple if check for array index check and initialize value 1

Tags: php

I have a string which has "23:22:0"

```
$string = "23:22:0";
$array = explode(":", $string);

if ($array[0] == 0) {
    $array[0] = 1;
}
if ($array[1] == 0) {
    $array[1] = 1;
}
if ($array[2] == 0) {
    $array[2] = 1;
}
```

How to avoid multiple if condition check here and i need this condition to be optimised in some best way. Any help is appreciated thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean optimized? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm checking each array index which has value 0 if so i will replace by value 1, i guess checking multiple if condition for this is not an optimised code.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by optimizing? More speed? Less memory usage?

Comment: @Terminus I'm trying to reduce the multiple if condition checks.

Comment: Different question: in your real code, does `$string` have more than 2 `:`s?

Comment: No always it will be 2

Comment: In that case, I say there's nothing wrong with having 3 if statements and I challenge anyone to come up with code that performs faster than this and or uses less memory Although, I still don't really see what this code is for.

Comment: Agree with that. If it's only three items then three ifs is fine

Answer (score 0):

Please check below example. I have commented out your $string variable and tested $string with '0:0:0' value.
Added print_r() to check whether the value is correct or not as we are expecting.
Hope it might be helpful.

```
//$string = "23:22:0";
$string = "0:0:0";
$array = explode(":", $string);

$array = array(
   0 => ($array[0] == 0) ? 1 : $array[0],
   1 => ($array[1] == 0) ? 1 : $array[1],
   2 => ($array[2] == 0) ? 1 : $array[2],
);

print_r($array);
```

Comment: It's the same thing as OP has.

Comment: @Andreas worse. It creates another array.

Answer (score 0):

> I wrote this answer because I thought there was an unknown number of items.
>   OP has now clarified that it's always three items. This is probably a bit overkill for the task at hand.

You can create a new array with 1's and use array_replace to merge it with the original array if you first remove the zero values.

```
$string = "23:22:0";
$array = explode(":", $string);

$fill = array_fill(0,count($array), 1); //create new array [1,1,1]
$array= array_filter($array); // remove zero values
$array= array_replace($fill,$array); // "merge" the arrays

var_dump($array);
```

Output:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "23"
  [1]=>
  string(2) "22"
  [2]=>
  int(1)
}
```

https://3v4l.org/thpfU

---

With three items in mind you can make the code look better with a loop.
It will perform about the same I believe.

```
foreach($array as &$val){
    if(!$val) $val=1;
}
```

Comment: I just added a bit of text to the answer. I didn't know it was only three items. This will handle any size of array. The if method used by OP and saif is static.